# First function called in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, macos

In an Swift application, you're supposedly supposed to put setup code in `applicationDidFinishLaunching()`. However, I noticed that in my Metal game, `viewDidLoad()` is called *first*. I have an `Init()` function I wrote, (written in C but bridged to Swift if that's important) that `fread`s settings from a file, and that the Metal game depends on. Putting this arbitrarily in `viewDidLoad()` is kinda awkward, but I guess in Objective-C the given first function called will be `main()`, but where is the `main()` function in Swift? Where is 'applicationDidStartLaunching' if you see what I mean? Where's the entry point of a Swift application?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The entry point is created behind the scenes by `@main` or `@NSApplicationMain` attribute. But if you want an explicit entry point, you can make one.

Create a *main.swift* file with the following contents:

```
import Cocoa
_ = NSApplicationMain(CommandLine.argc, CommandLine.unsafeArgv)
```

Now delete the `@main` or `@NSApplicationMain` attribute from the app delegate class declaration.

Run the app. It should behave normally.

Now if you have more code you want to inject very early, put it into *main.swift* before the NSApplicationMain call.